# How to block internet access for an application

Tags: internet, firewall

I'd search for a way to run an application prevent it from accessing internet, possibly without install a specific program to do this. Most of the answers I've found refers to [THIS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099&p=7460356#post7460356) post, so I tried this solution. In short words I had create a *no-internet* group (with a related *ni* command) and I launch the application using this group. But that does not work completely, probably because the post is from 2009, and something in iptables is changed (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04). For example if I run `ni "ping google.com"` the output is `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted`, so the solution works great. But with the other programs, like Firefox or wget (e.g. `ni firefox`), the internet connection still works. How can I solve?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apparmor` to deny network traffic for some application.
First you must install `apparmor` and `apparmor-utils` ..

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor*
```

After that you can generate profile to you application ...

```
sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Next step is to change `Networking` part in profile to:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser

audit deny network,
audit deny network inet stream,
deny network inet6 stream,
deny @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/if_inet6 r,
deny @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/ipv6_route r,
deny capability net_raw,
```

Next, check config with apparmor_parser and reload config

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser
```

Change mode from `complain` to `enforce` aka turn on `apparmor` for this app.

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser
```

More manual you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1008906) and [here](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apparmor-privoxy-profile/)

Comment: It does not work. Note that I have add the lines in the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.APPNAME` after the line `/usr/bin/APPNAME r,` and I don't know if it's right.