# How to control internet access (not LAN) for specific executable

Tags: networking, permissions, wine, internet, firewall

what I'd like to know is a way of denying internet access for one specific executable, like in Windows Firewall, where you can select a specific `.exe`-File and restrict it's access to internet.

Also, I'd like to have my programm still being able to access the LAN.

I already had a look at these three things:

- [This very old thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099)
- [the `unshare -n <myapp>` way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83348/276345)
- [this answer with AppArmor](https://askubuntu.com/a/679562/658718)

The answer AppArmor already comes very close, but the LAN part is missing.
Now, what I would like is an easy, preferably GUI-based way to do this.
Also important is that it's an application run through Wine, so it's no normal linux binary.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04, by the way.

Thanks in advance and cheers

Comment: Checkout this.. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/550276/how-to-block-internet-access-to-certain-programs-on-linux